# Como ativar a quebra de linha automática no PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

Olá gostaria de saber como ativar a quebra de linha automática no PyCharm, assim como fazemos no bloco de notas.

Answer (score 5):

No editor, clique com o botão direito sobre o número das linhas e ative "Soft-Wrap":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]